# Slow login for one user

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, login, startup-applications

I'm running a laptop Dell Inspiron 15R Core i7 with 16 GB RAM. I used to run it with an Ubuntu 14.04 and two days ago I've made a fresh new installation (but keeping the \home partition unchanged) of Ubuntu 16.04.

The problem is: boot is fast enough and login for one user is also very fast (ca. 2 seconds). But login for the other user is very slow (ca. 10-12 seconds). It was already so with Ubuntu 14.04 and I thought it would change with a fresh installation, but don't. It remains the same. I've taken a look at the startup programs and disabled all applications except key storage, indicator application and Gnome software, the only three that appear to the other user (which logins very fast). But it hasn't changed the login speed.

How can I identify what's going on and fix it? THanks!

Comment: Look at the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` to see if something is off for that user.